# Using Venue search with startAT and endAt information

Tags: foursquare

I want to know how many check-ins has happened in a particular interval of time (foursquare venue search with startAt and endAt timestamp) at a location. (I have its geo-corrdinates)

So, I am trying to use FourSquare Venue Search with startAt and endAt information. The command works and  gives output, but results are same as if without startAt and endAt term.

Example with start and end timestamp,  `https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=-34.02977,151.10533&radius=100&startAt=1287421200&endAt=1287428399&limit=50`

but the above command give almost the same result as

`https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=-34.02977,151.10533&radius=100&limit=50`

1) I am wondering if Foursquare and kept an option to add these parameters and processes them ?

2) Although mentioned on FourSquare's website that all Venue API do not require authentication, "Venue Stats" does (it can solve my problem)

3) any possible solution is welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

startAt and endAt are not supported parameters for venue/search. Granular information about check-in history for a venue are only made available to the venue's manager.